# How do I prove that the following set is limited?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, supremum-and-infimum

I have this set:

$M=\left\{\frac{1}{n^{2}}-\frac{2}{m}:n,m\in\mathbb{Z}\setminus \left\{0 \right\}\right\}$

How do I prove it's bounded? Additionally, how can I decide the infimum and supremum? I thought an initial attempt at solving it would be to join the two terms like so:

$a_{n}=\frac{1}{n^{2}}-\frac{2}{m}=\frac{m-2n^{2}}{n^{2}m}$

But where to go from there? I have been advised against using limits, introduced in secondary school, but I don't know any other way.

Also, if you have any advise on how to get better at "identifying" solutions (I feel like a lot of it is basically algebra) that would be amazing!

Comment: Look at the terms individually, are they bounded? When are they lowest and when are they highest?

Comment: @kingW3 when n is approaching infinity, the term approaches zero. Conversely, when n is approaching 0, the term approaches infinity. When m approaches infinity, the term approaches zero. Conversely, when m approaches zero, the term approaches infinity. As m approaches negative zero (?) the term is also positive. Therefore, the highest should be when n and m are approaching zero and negative zero respectively, and the lowest should be when n approaches infinity and m approaches negative zero, right?

Comment: Note that you are dealing with non-zero integers so you cannot get too close to zero ...

Comment: @MarkBennet Cheers Mark! Then that would mean 1/n^2 is at its lowest when n is approaching infinity, and to make the difference as large as possible 2/m would have m=1. 1/n^2 is at its largest when n=1, and -2/m is at its largest when m=-1. So infM=-2 and supM=3. Is that all there is to it? When answering, do I use limits to prove that these are indeed the infimum and supremum of the set?

Comment: If you can show that a function is increasing (or decreasing) on an interval the supremum (infimum) can only be found in one place (if it exists) ...